# How to run several scripts in differents folders on Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to run a lot of scripts for paper, and I would like to make this automatic. I have several folders (P1, P2,..., PN) in which I have  a script ( test1, test2, ... testN) and I need to run all this, but doing on by one by myself I waste a lot of time that I don't have!

[image]

[image]

I tried subprocess:

[image]

where P1_T1 is:

```
for i in range(5):
    x = i+2*i
   
    print(x)
```

and P1_T2 is:

```
for i in range(5):
    x = i+3*i
    print(x)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: you need them to run simultaneously is what you mean by it didn’t work?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you get an error? If so, what was it? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Also, instead of writing each `Popen` by hand, you should use a loop instead.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I don't need to run simultaneously, I just need to run one by one, but this way is not showing any result on the screen, this was just a test, in my real code I have a .txt file as output, and has not been produced with this subprocess code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recurse through a set of directories, I recommend using os.walk. This implementation should attempt to run POpen 'python [filename]' on every file in your root directory:

```
import os
import importlib.util


path = "C:\\SO\\testfolder" # <--- replace this with the path to the folder containing all of your p1, p2, p3, p4 folders.

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        if file_extension == ".py":
            print("Now Executing: " + filename + "-----------")
            spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(file, file_path)
            module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
            spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Edit: Added in use of import library+exec_module to run the python files. Import method referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path/67692#67692).

Comment: Is there another way to run a script from a folder without POpen?

Comment: This code didn't work, I got the error:     raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")

TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: I am looking into using importlib to run it, give me a moment to test it

Comment: I figure out what is, it was missing [ ]; This way run without erros but doesnt shows the results : import subprocess
import os

path = 'C:/Users/Familia/OneDrive - Università di Cagliari/PhD/simpegmaster/Notebooks/Testes_Jenny/TEMFAST/TEMFAST Work/Castanheira/Teste'


for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        subprocess.run(['python',os.path.join(root,file)])

Comment: That's good, I found a way to run so that print statements are still done, give me a moment to finish testing it and I'll update my answer

Comment: I made an improved version, by using some code for import lib + exec. Try running this version, it should hopefully allow you to run and get the proper outputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199530/discussion-between-jeniffer-barreto-and-enthus3d).

Comment: Hopefully the rest of your paper/project goes well!

Comment: No problem :). Glad I could help you out. If you ever need me to go into more detail about how the implementation works, feel free to comment/use the chat.

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` expects list of arguments, so what about

```py
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

Popen(['python', 'p1/P1_T1.py'])
time.sleep(1)
Popen(['python','p2/P2_T1.py'])
```

Does this work for you? There is nice tutorial  - [Python 3 Subprocess Examples](http://queirozf.com/entries/python-3-subprocess-examples)

Comment: No, this doesn't work. No error, but no result, doesn't show anything on the screen. Like in the photo that I have add